# Android Dialog - Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Dialog.dismiss()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, dialog

I have a `showImagePreviewDialog` function where I am calling dismissDialog which contains the code for dialog dismiss:

```
    private void showImagePreviewDialog(@Nullable final byte[] bitmapData) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapData, 0, bitmapData.length);
        Matrix mat = new Matrix();
        mat.postRotate(90);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), mat, true);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imv_photo_preview);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        // Ok button listener
        Button btn_ok = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok_photo_dialog);
        btn_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onOkPressed(bitmapData, false);
            }
        });
        // Discard button listener
        Button btn_discard = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_discard_photo_dialog);
        btn_discard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismissDialog();
            }
        });

        // Show dialog
        dialog.show();
```

Here is `dismissDialog` method:

```
    private void dismissDialog() {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
```

I am initializing in the  acitivity `onCreate`:

```
    private Dialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ....
        dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        // Set dialog view
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.display_preview);
    }
```

is there any possibility if we go back from the activity and the activity resumes then dialog will become null ? I cannot figure out how this error occurs

Comment: Why don't you just create and use the dialog where you need it instead of making it a class member?

Comment: @TylerV I created the dialog locally previously, I got the same error. So I decided to instantiate it in `onCreate`. But again it is not working in that way.